# How to display the result returned from Oraclize's _callback function in dapp frontend?

Tags: contract-design, truffle, testrpc, oracles

I am using testrpc as client and truffle as development framework.And also using ethereum-bridge for Oraclize.

This is the contract code.I have downloaded the 'Oraclize API' (oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol)from the Oraclize github repo.I have added this file to the truffle contracts folder, and rename the file to usingOraclize.sol.And it is imported in the given contract.

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

  import "./usingOraclize.sol";

  contract ApiCall is usingOraclize {

        uint public DieselPriceUSD;

        function ApiCall() {

                OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x9851eb2d10b765d8857e7e1b060bc1eb166e89f2);
        }

        function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
                if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
                DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); 
        }

        function update() payable {
                oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
         }

     }
```

The XML file in the link 'https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices' is as follows.

```
     <fuelPrices>
          <cng>2.06</cng>
          <diesel>2.57</diesel>
          <e85>1.93</e85>
          <electric>0.13</electric>
          <lpg>2.68</lpg>
          <midgrade>2.58</midgrade>
          <premium>2.82</premium>
          <regular>2.33</regular>
  </fuelPrices>
```

I have compiled the contract using 'truffle'
[image]
The Oraclize return the result diesel price as '2.57' using ethereum-bridge.

[image]

I want to use the result in index.js file to display it in frontend.How to use the result in dapp frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the result in your contract, log it as an event. Using web3.js or ethjs, make JavaScript code to listen for that event (see the docs for `watch` or `filter`), and display it on your HTML page.

Comment: @ Edmund Edgar Can you please mention the updations required in _callback function for logging the result as event?I have no idea about it

Comment: See here for how to create an event and listen to it from JavaScript: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events